# Textfile Structure (tables)

Tags: php, mysql, text

Alright, I know I have had a lot of help on here recently with writing queries in php and outputting them to a text file. I have finally grasped and learned how to actually do that much (thanks guys!). The code below show what I do have:

Now I know the table structure (th/tr/td) does not work in a text file. I was wondering if anyone knew how to get this into a traditional "column" view like:

```
id   ||   title   ||   keyword
================================
2    ||   bob     ||   jones
2    ||   bob     ||   jones
2    ||   bob     ||   jones
2    ||   bob     ||   jones
```

I dont necessarily need borders or anything just at least an easy to read format. This outputted file will be used by google products for the company I work for (and they need an easy to read format I believe, or just something that is set up in a table form. I could do a CSV, but I know less about that then I do php. Thanks again.

Comment: CSV is a stupendously simple format, especially since PHP has functions to deal with it. It'd be a lot easier than fake tables, especially if it's supposed to be parsed automatically.

Comment: By the way this was somewhat of a simplified example. If someone asked me to build a report from a SQL query, I would do it in phpMyadmin and export the results as an Excel file. Otherwise you have to continually modify the SQL, formatting, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's see how we can do this. I'm just going to focus on the relevant header printing and displaying formatted results. So then, in this case we're going to use [fprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fprintf.php) to print some fancy formatted text to our file in question here. So here's basically how will do this:

```
id   ||   title   ||   keyword
```

First off we need to make some widths for these fields so everything shows up in a nice fashion. We'll set a width of 10 for each:

```
fprintf($fh, "%-10s || %-10s || %-10s\n", "id", "title", "keyword");
```

What this `%-10s` does is tell us that we want a string formatted with a width of 10 characters, with spaces used for padding if the length is not enough. You can adjust the 10 to be whatever width you'd like in order to get the best result. The result comes out to something like this:

```
id         || title      || keyword
```

Next we print out our divider, which I just tweaked the length a bit until it came out the same:

```
fprintf($fh, "===================================\n");
```

Then we loop through and print out our values:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  fwrite($fh, "%-10s || %-10s || %-10s\n" $row['card_id'], $row['title'],  $row['description']);
}
```

Which will give us something like this:

```
id         || title      || keyword   
===================================
2          || bob        || jones     
2          || bob        || jones     
2          || bob        || jones     
2          || bob        || jones
```

And that's it! Here is the full code for reference:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
 mysql_connect("mysql4.host.net", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("amyadele_test") or die(mysql_error()); 

// Query the database for data
$query = "SELECT card_id,title,description FROM cards";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Open file for writing
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

// Loop through returned data and write (append) directly to file
fprintf($fh, "%-10s || %-10s || %-10s\n", "id", "title", "keyword");
fprintf($fh, "===================================\n");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  fprintf($fh, "%-10s || %-10s || %-10s\n", $row['card_id'], $row['title'], $row['description']);
}

// Close out the file
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: +1 The problem is, what do you do with titles/keywords longer than 10 characters...?

Comment: @deceze indeed that could become an issue, which is why I made the comment on being able to adjust the widths accordingly. The ID field could have been made shorter to be honest

Comment: @deceze There's probably a way to do it dynamically by first getting the length of the longest keyword, but I'd rather not complicate the example too much

Answer (score 3):

CSV is trivial with [`fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/fputcsv):

```
$fh = fopen('output.csv', 'w') or die("can't open file");

// output header and first row
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
fputcsv($fh, array_keys($row));
fputcsv($fh, $row);

// output the remaining rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row);
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Indeed, a better solution using php builtin functions. I was asking myself why you didn't provide an answer yourself. :) Well done!